# is there a way to use java reflection to find a class using the classes variable?

Tags: java, reflection

for example

say you had

```
public abstract class class1 {

}

public class2 extends class1 {
String id = "id_for_class2"
}

public class3 extends class1 {
String id = "id_for_class3"
}

public class4 extends class1 {
String id = "id_for_class4"}
```

And you want to use reflection to get a specific class based on the id.

Is there a way to do this using reflection in java?

Comment: While it’s possible to do what you describe, you really should use [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) for finding implementations of an abstract class or interface.

Comment: Your `id` fields are instance fields. So you’d have to create instances of a class you don’t known, in order to read the field. If you know the classes in advance, there is no point in comparing an additional id. What would be the advantage of `c = hypotheticalMethod("id_for_class3")` over `c = class3.class`? Also worth reading [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of id like below. This example will print "id_for_class2".

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        class1 a = new class2();

        Class cls = a.getClass();
        Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("id");
        Object value = field.get(a);

        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```